# Can two capacitors be used in series to get an equivalent capacitance in a circuit?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I am building an FM radio circuit and a 27pF capacitor (ceramic) is required in that, but I don't have one. But I do have 56pF capacitors. So I was thinking that I can  use two 56pF in series to get an equivalent 28pF.

Is it possible and will it affect the circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

And FM radio is *not* DC; it actually involves frequencies around 100 MHz.

Comment: Sir i have another doubt. what is the difference between Ceramic filters and crystal oscillators. Can filter be substituted by the crystal oscillator?

Comment: That's an entirely separate topic. You should start a new question for that one.